# Call api on new order hook parameter in PrestaShop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am developing a module in PrestaShop, I have to call an API, I have achieved call on new/update/delete product, but now I want to have new order call.

I am using 1.6 so I just need to fields.
[image: Fields]

This is my module code

```
public function hookNewOrder($order){
        $data=[
            'shipping_data'=>'',
            'shipping_time'=>'',
            'greetings'=>'',
            'recipient_name'=>'',
            'phone'=>''
        ];
        $response = Requests::post('https://izer.co.il/crm/product_api.php',[],json_encode($data));
        file_put_contents(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . $this->name .'/log.json',json_encode($response,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    }
```

I just want to correctly filled order details in data array. Everything else is working fine, I do not exactly know what will be the nature of $order object passed to this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just debug this $order variable in your hook call and see what is inside.

```
public function hookNewOrder($order)
{
    var_dump($order);
    die();
}
```

Basically, $order contains a lot of data but I'm not sure that it has that what you need. And do not forget to register the hook before usage in your install method

```
public function install()
{
    ....
    $this->registerHook('newOrder')
    ....
}
```